# Create function to normalize path and then join

Tags: python, linux, window

I am trying to create a function that will take in a list of paths (from the parameter list), execute several functions from os.path on it (expandvars, expanduser, normpath), and finally join all those path values. So far it looks like this:

```
def normjoin(*p):
    """ Uses os.path functions to normalize and join paths
       *path - all the paths you want to join
       return: normalized and joined string
    """
    b_results = []
    for b in p:
        b_results.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.expandvars(os.path.expanduser(b))))
    return os.path.join(b_results)
```

And this is how it looks in practice:

```
sharedir = normjoin("~", "Dropbox/SpideroakShared")
```

I plan to use this on both a win and linux system.

The return value will come looking like this `' "C:\\Users\\tgoldie", "Dropbox\\SpideroakShared"'` which is not good.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body of the function should be indented.

You have `b_results = ""`, but then try to `append`. That won't work. You need `b_results = []`.

Finally, you need to pass the items of `b_results` as arguments to `os.path.join` like this:

```
return os.path.join(*b_results)
```

Comment: Fixed the miss-formatting in my message (thankfully not in the actual code.) The * in the join() function was the trick. Does the * "split up" the list, or is it just a way to send arguments to a function? Thanks!

Comment: It takes the elements of a list and sends them as arguments to a function (in other words, it denests the list). For example, `f(*[1, 2, 3])` is the same as `f(1, 2, 3)`.